# Case-insensitive htaccess 301

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I have about 300 redirects in the following format

`Redirect 301   /post/My-Blog-Post.aspx https://www.example.com/blog/a-new-post/`

That works great except the redirects are case sensitive and going to `/post/my-blog-post.aspx` doesn't redirect.

There isn't a pattern for the old URL to new URL so this would likely have to be a flag for every redirect.

**How can I get the URL to redirect no matter the case?**

Comment: Why was this closed as off topic?

Comment: Because a *.htaccess* topic without any REGEX is an off topic and belongs on: http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 11):

Don't think there's a way to make the `Redirect` directive (part of mod_alias) case insensitive, but there's a mod_rewrite flag that you can use. You'll need to change all of your redirects from this:

```
 Redirect 301 /post/My-Blog-Post.aspx https://www.example.com/blog/a-new-post/
```

to:

```
 RewriteRule ^/?post/My-Blog-Post.aspx$ https://www.example.com/blog/a-new-post/ [L,R=301,NC]
```

Note the `NC` flag, meaning "no case". This will match any URI that looks like `/post/my-blog-post.aspx` and ignores case, and redirects it to `https://www.example.com/blog/a-new-post/`.

Comment: No dice -- same result.

Comment: Adding the NC flag worked on a couple of different sites for me, one server running Apache 2.2 and another on 2.4. Check Apache's documentation, it is consistent with Jon Lin's answer: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_nc

Answer (score 1):

However, if you want to make *"My-Blog-Post"* a variable of *"a-new-post"*, I mean if you want */post/My-Blog-Post.aspx* to be redirected into */blog/a-new-post/* either */post/**this**.aspx* into */blog/**this**/* or */post/**that**.aspx* into */blog/**that**/* or even */post/**anything**.aspx* into */blog/**anything**/*, you can try to use this code in you `.htaccess` hidden file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^post/([a-z0-9-_]+).aspx$ /blog/$1/ [R=301,NC]
```